# I am looking for a place in Scandinavia

Tags: identify-this, norway, scandinavia

I am looking for a place in Scandinavia, most likely in Norway. Problem is, I have image of it in my head, but I completely forgot it's whereabouts.

I have seen once a picture of it on 9gag, but it wasn't explicitly stated or marked as Norway (except for the comment section, else I'd have found it already).

It looked like this (It looks much better in my mind, but thanks to my MS Paint skills it had lost a bit of detail)
[image: a metal bridge into nothing between fjords]

In my mind it depicts a view of a city between fjords with a river (sea?), taken from a viewpoint on  metal footbridge? (It was clearly a viewpoint, bridges in English normally connect to other end. This was simply a 'ladder to the sky')

Comment: There seem to be [a lot of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=norway+bridge+viewpoint&rlz=1C1CHKB_en-gbNZ607NZ607&espv=2&biw=1112&bih=1040&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_uefj9vvNAhXGoJQKHeVxBwEQsAQIGQ) in Norway. Any clues there?

Comment: ["...There is a tree like this!  And a man in a suit!..."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAdq2wRnVRI) (Russian)  Maybe some clues about where your where before and after?

Comment: Voted to leave open. Whoever gets this gets to be crowned TSE identify-this world champion!

Comment: It seems you've been back a couple of times. Do you have anything to add about the view point? You're at 3 close votes so far

Comment: This is one of the funniest questions I've seen and I use many of the SE sites... upvote just for that :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or from the viewpoint at Bergsbotn, Senja
[image]

Better yet, it may be the Romsdalsstrappa overlook, compliments of [Friluftslek](http://www.friluftslek.no/)
[image]

Comment: @pnuts: done, crediting Friluftslek. I Google image searched 'Norway' without any other hints, as previously (overlook, fjord, views, national trail, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

How about [Stegastein](https://www.visitflam.com/en/se-og-gjore/aktiviteter/stegastein-roundtrip/) viewpoint?

[image]

Comment: Houses down below. Footbridge was "metal footbridge?". Certainly not saying it's right, but perhaps it could jog the OPs memory and we could get a bit closer